# Python: Iterating through list keeps failing

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have been trying to figure the following out for two days; hopefully someone can show me what i am doing wrong

I have created a function in which i want to iterate through a list as many times as there are list entries

For some reason my FOR LOOP fails after the first loop.  I have checked the list created ("links") has at least 2 entries by placing a PRINT LEN on the list, so i cannot for the life of me work out why after just one time through the loop exits

I have added a PRINT("FOR LOOP STARTS") so i can track what the loop is doing and actually before it fails it does display the text a second time but it never displays the next PRINT command which suggests to me its failing at the "VALUE = link.text" part, but again I don't really understand why

Any help would be most grateful

```
def MULTIHIT():

 try: 


      links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@href, 'MyData=')]")

      for link in links:

           print("FOR LOOP STARTS")

           value = link.text
           print(value)

           driver.get('www.somewebsite.com')

           driver.find_element_by_name("searchValue").click()
           driver.find_element_by_name("searchValue").send_keys(value)

           driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@name='sub']").click()

           #collect a value from an excel file and remove spaces
           cellvalue = str(sheet.cell(i, 1).value) 
           cellvalue2 = cellvalue.replace(" ", "")

           #collect a value from a webpage and remove spaces
           checkoff = driver.find_element_by_id("somedata")
           checkoff2 = checkoff.text.replace(" ", "")

           #if two values match, call another function
           if checkoff2 == cellvalue2:
                MAS()

 except:
      print("something went wrong")
```

EDIT:

Upon the advice given I have used my TRY and EXCEPT in a way that doesn't hide the error.  The error being posted is:

"Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document....."

I have googled this and as i understand it the error is thrown because I have since navigated away from the page where an element once existed.  But now i am wondering how/why this can be.....I am under the impression that `links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@href, 'MyData=')]")` creates a list called LINKS and that the FOR loop just iterates through an otherwise static and closed list.

is this not the case?

EDIT 2:

So I played with the idea that the list created by `find_elements` is really just pointing to `driver` to get the element again.  So what i did was this:

```
def MULTIHIT():

 try: 


      links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@href, 'MyData=')]")
      links2 = []

      for link in links:
           links2.append(link.text)

      for link in links:

           print("FOR LOOP STARTS")

           value = link
           print(value)

           driver.get('www.somewebsite.com')

           driver.find_element_by_name("searchValue").click()
           driver.find_element_by_name("searchValue").send_keys(value)

           driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@name='sub']").click()

           #collect a value from an excel file and remove spaces
           cellvalue = str(sheet.cell(i, 1).value) 
           cellvalue2 = cellvalue.replace(" ", "")

           #collect a value from a webpage and remove spaces
           checkoff = driver.find_element_by_id("somedata")
           checkoff2 = checkoff.text.replace(" ", "")

           #if two values match, call another function
           if checkoff2 == cellvalue2:
                MAS()

 except:
      print("something went wrong")
```

This is a very "ugly" solution (creating multiple lists) but it works.  If anyone happens to have a more pythonic way of achieving the same i would still be interested to know

Thanks for help